# Find and extract text between delimiters R

Tags: r, delimiter, text-extraction

I have the following data string

```
    Seat_WASHER<-
  structure(
    list(
      Description = c(
        "SEAT WASHER, MR2, 8\", TN 10.12, CR 150/600, 316 Stainless Steel",
        "SEAT WASHER, 1\", TN 1.42, CR 950/1200, MR1, 316 Stainless Steel",
        "SEAT WASHER, 3\", TN 1.52,  MR1, 316 Stainless Steel",
        "SEAT WASHER, MR1, 2\", TN 1.62, CR 800/1200, 316 Stainless Steel",
        "SEAT WASHER, MR1, TN 2.12, 1/2\", CR 150/600, 316 Stainless Steel",
        "SEAT WASHER, MR6, 2\", TN 6.48, CR 750/100, 316 Stainless Steel"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-7L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

It's a very large data set and is not consistent in it's order or contents with strings.

How do I find key indicators (", CR, MR), and pull all data between the delimiters into a column? If it can't find the key indicator in the string it'll need to output NULL.

Finding all CR will result in a column like:

```html
Col 1 
--------
CR 150/600
CR 950/1200
NULL
CR 800/1200
CR 150/600
CR 750/100
```

Comment: I want all of the ones with the same key indicators in the same columns. For example,

|col1    |col2     |col3         |col4
|MR1    |2"        |TN 6.48    |CR 750/1000
|''         |''           |''               |''

Comment: Would you `dput(data_string)` and edit your question and paste the result?

Comment: Yeah, let me look up how to do that. I'm new to this platform so thank you for you patience.

Comment: assuming you `my_horror_data <- read.csv(` , `dput(head(my_horror_data))`, then copy `structure(...)` as data above.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Try the answer attached .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(stringr)

Seat_WASHER$col1 <- str_extract(Seat_WASHER$Description , "CR \\d+/\\d+")
```

- output

```
         col1
1  CR 150/600
2 CR 950/1200
3        <NA>
4 CR 800/1200
5  CR 150/600
6  CR 750/100
```

Comment: If you want to add another columns , just change the pattern in the function `str_extract` like `Seat_WASHER$col2 <- str_extract(Seat_WASHER$Description , "TN \\d+\\.\\d+")
` to extract all TN results

Answer (score 0):

If it is always split by a comma you can use strsplit to separate the string then find where `CR` is located using `grep()`, specify value = TRUE to return the value. I added trimws to remove the leading space.

```
m1 <- "SEAT WASHER, MR6, 2\", TN 6.48, CR 750/100, 316 Stainless Steel"
m2 <- strsplit(m1,",") 
trimws(grep("CR",m2[[1]], value = TRUE))
```

### edit based on data

Still will string split and then keep where CR is in`m3` before appending to data turn all length 0 vectors to NA

```
m2 <-   strsplit(Seat_WASHER$Description,",") 
m3 <- sapply(m2, function(x) trimws(grep("CR",x, value = TRUE)))

Seat_WASHER$newcol <- sapply(m3, function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)
```